# Spring webflux and spring boot starter graphql doesn't return nullable field

Tags: spring-webflux, apollo, spring-boot-starter-graphql

I have created  **spring web flux** with **graphql** using the following dependenies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and my **graphql endpoin**t

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
private final UserService userService;


public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@SneakyThrows
@QueryMapping
public Flux<User> getUser() {
    return userService.findAllUsers();
}
```

and **User** Object

```
public class User extends ReusableField implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;
private String email;

private String fieldNullable;
....
```

The field **fieldNullable** is not returned from the graphql response hence **apollo-garaphql** for angular display console error "Missing field '**fieldNullable**' while writing result"

how can I make spring return this field whether it is null or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.I had a bean definition

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```

The issue is ith this line `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);`

Changing to `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS);`

solved the problem`